# Issue in Erasing of image by CoreGraphics after rotating the same image by Gestures?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, core-graphics, uigesturerecognizer

Currently, I am stuck with a bit dangerous issue. What i am doing is erasing an image with help of core graphics and applying rotation effect on that same image. When i just erase the image, the erasing is working accurately, but when i rotate that image first and then erase that same image. the image is getting blur and the height of the image is reducing as i am moving to erase any particular pixel of image. Here is the code snippet which i am using to erase the image:-

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        mPreviousPoints = [touch locationInView:self];
        mPreviousPoints.y = mPreviousPoints.y ;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        currentPoint.y = currentPoint.y ;

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
        CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetBlendMode(currentContext,kCGBlendModeClear);
        CGContextSetLineCap(currentContext, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, 20);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, mPreviousPoints.x , mPreviousPoints.y );
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, currentPoint.x , currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(currentContext) ;
        self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

The code is working properly, if i do not rotate the image.

I tried to rotate the image with touch events also but there was no change, so here is code for scrolling that i am using in my App:-

```
#pragma mark Rotation Gesture

- (void)rotateImage:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
if (objAppDelegate.touchBool == YES)
{
    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        previousRotation = 0.0;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat newRotation = 0.0 - (previousRotation - [recognizer rotation]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransformation = touchImageView.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransformation, newRotation);

    touchImageView.transform = newTransform;

    previousRotation = [recognizer rotation];
}
}
```

I am posting the screenshots, so that you can understand my problem properly. So, Please have a look on it and help me.

[image: Original Image]

[image: Image after applying erase effect only]

[image: Image after rotation]

[image: Image after rotation and erasing]

Please help me if you can!

Thanks in advance :)